# Replace app config with instance in tests using Options pattern

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, testing, dependency-injection

I use the [C# Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options), e. g. with a config type like this:

```cs
public class MySettings
{
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfDays { get; set; }
}
```

Within my tests, I want to configure ASP.NET's DI container so that it always provides the same instance of `MySettings`, e. g. like this (which does not compile as `Configure<T>` does not accept an instance of `T`):

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    private readonly MySettings settings;

    public CustomWebApplicationFactory(MySettings settings)
        : base()
     => _settings = settings;

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

        builder.ConfigureServices(services => services.Configure<MySettings>(_settings));
    }
}
```

At the moment, I'm working around this by specifying a configuration lambda like this:

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    private readonly Action<MySettings> _configureSettings;

    public CustomWebApplicationFactory(Action<MySettings> configureSettings)
        : base()
     => _configureSettings = configureSettings;

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

        builder.ConfigureServices(services => services.Configure<MySettings>(_configureSettings));
    }
}
```

If I could pass an instance of `MySettings`, it would make the test code slightly more readable.

Thx!

Comment: `services.Configure<MySettings>(_ => _settings)`

Comment: I would suggest having a look at this article https://andrewlock.net/reloading-strongly-typed-options-when-appsettings-change-in-asp-net-core-rc2/

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be an overkill for a pretty simple problem, but let's roll with it!

In order to force ASP.NET Core built-in DI container to always return the same instance of `IOptions<T>` you provide, we can add another layer on top of the existing `IOptions<T>` system. Normally, options are created using `IOptionsFactory` and thus can go through [multiple configure callbacks](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/src/OptionsFactory.cs#L58). Let us reuse available `OptionsManager<T>` and override its `Get()` method so we can intercept calls originating from the `Value` property getter and steer them to alternative path, if we decide so.

```cs
public class CachedOptionsManager<TOptions> : OptionsManager<TOptions>, IOptions<TOptions>
    where TOptions : class
{
    private readonly OptionsInMemoryStore _optionsInMemoryStore;

    public CachedOptionsManager(
        OptionsInMemoryStore optionsInMemoryStore,
        IOptionsFactory<TOptions> optionsFactory)
        : base(optionsFactory)
    {
        _optionsInMemoryStore = optionsInMemoryStore;
    }

    public override TOptions Get(string name)
    {
        if (_optionsInMemoryStore.TryGet<TOptions>(name, out var options))
        {
            return options;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.Get(name);
        }
    }
}
```

With the `Get()` calls being intercepted, we need to store and obtain the options instances from somewhere. Below is an in-memory store for options. Notice how it's created from instances of `OptionsInstance`, which are  provided by DI.

```cs
public class OptionsInMemoryStore
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>> _options;

    public OptionsInMemoryStore(IEnumerable<OptionsInstance> optionsInstances)
    {
        var values = optionsInstances
            .GroupBy(x => x.Instance.GetType())
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToDictionary(x => x.Name ?? Options.DefaultName, x => x.Instance));

        _options = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>>(values);
    }

    public bool TryGet<T>(string name, out T options)
        where T : class
    {
        options = default;

        if (!_options.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var optionsInstances))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!optionsInstances.TryGetValue(name, out var instance))
        {
            return false;
        }

        options = (T)instance;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Simple wrapper for options, the `OptionsInstance`:

```cs
public class OptionsInstance
{
    public OptionsInstance(object instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
    }

    public OptionsInstance(string name, object instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
        Name = name;
    }

    public object Instance { get; }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

But we still need to register those `OptionsInstances` and other stores. Here, extension methods come in. The `AddOptionsSingleInstance()` will enable the feature of single instance options. It also adds the store for options and replaces the default implementation of `IOptions<T>` with our custom `CachedOptionsManager<T>`. Same for `IOptionsSnapshot<T>`. Below are extension methods with overload for named options, if needed.

```cs
public static class OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddOptionsSingleInstance(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.TryAddSingleton<OptionsInMemoryStore>();
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(IOptions<>), typeof(CachedOptionsManager<>));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IOptionsSnapshot<>), typeof(CachedOptionsManager<>));

        return services;
    }

    public static IServiceCollection Configure<T>(this IServiceCollection services, T instance)
        where T : class
    {
        return services.AddSingleton(new OptionsInstance(instance));
    }

    public static IServiceCollection Configure<T>(this IServiceCollection services, string name, T instance)
        where T : class
    {
        return services.AddSingleton(new OptionsInstance(name, instance));
    }
}
```

Usage showcase:

```cs
var williamSettings = new MySettings
{
    NumberOfDays = 22,
};

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddOptions<MySettings>().Configure(x => x.NumberOfDays = 101);
services.AddOptions<MySettings>("Jean settings").Configure(x => x.NumberOfDays = 303);
services.AddOptionsSingleInstance();
services.Configure(williamSettings);

using var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();

var options1 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MySettings>>();
var options2 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<MySettings>>();
var options1Name = options1.Value.NumberOfDays;
var options2Name = options2.Get("Jean settings").NumberOfDays;

Debug.Assert(options1Name.Equals(22));
Debug.Assert(options2Name.Equals(303));
```

In your `WebApplicationFactory` case, it would be just:

```cs
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

    builder.ConfigureServices(services => 
    {
        services.AddOptionsSingleInstance();
        services.Configure<MySettings>(_settings);
    });
}
```

This will work when resolving `IOptions<T>` or `IOptionsSnapshot<T>`. Anything above it, like manually creating options from factory or using `IOptionsMonitor<T>` will require additional code.